# adding listbox value with multi value select to sql database in php

Tags: php, sql, forms

i am trying to add multiple values to my SQL table (program_celebrity) from a form post, i have in my form post the following, reads another table like this:

```
<label for="ProgramListing"></label>
    <select name="ProgramListing" style="width: 800px;" size="10" multiple id="ProgramListing">
      <?php
            $sql_program_listing = "SELECT * FROM program order by ProgramName ASC"; 
            foreach($conn->query($sql_program_listing) as $row_program_listing){ ?>
      <option value="<?=$row_program_listing["ProgramCode"];?>" <?php if ($row_programlisting["id_program"] == $registrant['id_program']) echo 'selected="selected"';?>><?=$row_program_listing["ProgramName"];?> (<?=$row_program_listing["ReleaseDate"] .")";?>
        </option>
      <?php } ?>
      </select>
```

What works fine
now i would like to add this with information that comes as follows:

```
$id_celebrity = $_POST['id_celebrity'];
$id_program_celebrity = $_POST['id_celebrity']+$_POST['ProgramListing'];
```

And i use:

```
foreach ($_POST['ProgramListing'] as $id_program)
{
$sql_connect_celebrity = "INSERT INTO 
        program_celebrity 
        (
        id_program,
        id_celebrity,
        id_program_celebrity
        )
        VALUES 
        (?,?,?)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_connect_celebrity);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $id_program);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $id_celebrity);
$stmt->bindValue(3, $id_program_celebrity);
$stmt->execute();
}
```

But it works fine when i post just one selection, but i would like the form to post multiple selections and register them in the table. Can't seem to get it right, any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change your form

`<select name="ProgramListing" style="width: 800px;" size="10" multiple id="ProgramListing">`

to

`<select name="ProgramListing[]" style="width: 800px;" size="10" multiple id="ProgramListing">`